# merge 2 sql query location and average rating

Tags: php, mysql

How can I merge these two sql queries on one query?

```
$query2 ="select raiting.rated_user,avg(raiting.rate) as `avg_rating` from raiting,users  where
raiting.rated_user=user_id  group by raiting.rated_user order by avg(raiting.rate) desc";

$query      = “SELECT `user_id`,`name`,`email`,`degree`,`avatar`,`mobile`,`sex`,`nationality`,`nationalitycode`,`birthday_year`,`pr_hour`,`spicality`,`city`,`online`,`intro`, (SQRT(POW((lat - $lat), 2) + POW((lang - $lang), 2)) * $multiplier) AS distance FROM users  WHERE POW((lat - $lat), 2) + POW((lang - $lang), 2) < POW(($distance / $multiplier), 2) ORDER BY distance";
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry its MySQL Query

Answer (score 1):

Use the first one as a subquery in the second one:

```
$query = "
 SELECT
      `user_id`,`name`,`email`,`degree`,`avatar`,`mobile`
      ,`sex`,`nationality`,`nationalitycode`,`birthday_year`,`pr_hour`
      ,`spicality`,`city`,`online`
      ,`intro`
      , (SQRT(POW((lat - $lat), 2) + POW((lang - $lang), 2)) * $multiplier) AS distance 
      , r.`avg_rating`
 FROM users 
 INNER JOIN (
      select
            raiting.rated_user
           ,avg(raiting.rate) as `avg_rating` 
      from raiting
      group by raiting.rated_user 
      ) AS r  on users.user_id  = raiting.rated_user
 WHERE POW((lat - $lat), 2) + POW((lang - $lang), 2) < POW(($distance / $multiplier), 2) 
 ORDER BY distance
";
```

---

SQL queries can be spread over multiple rows, makes it way easier to maintain

Take precautions to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on also:

```
$query = "SELECT `user_id`,`name`,`email`,`degree`,`avatar`, `mobile`,`sex`,`nationality`, `nationalitycode`,`birthday_year`,`pr_hour`,
`spicality`,`city`,`online`,`intro`,t1.rated_user,t1.avg_rating
(SQRT(POW((lat - $lat), 2) + POW((lang - $lang), 2)) * $multiplier) AS distance 
FROM users inner join (select raiting.rated_user,avg(raiting.rate) as `avg_rating` from raiting 
group by raiting.rated_user 
order by avg(raiting.rate) desc) t1 on users.user_id = t1.rated_user
WHERE POW((lat - $lat), 2) + POW((lang - $lang), 2) < POW(($distance / $multiplier), 2) 
ORDER BY distance";
```